# Are there countries where businesses allowed to charge what the market will bear without being harassed, fined, or imprisoned by state actors?

Tags: is-x-legal

According [to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_gouging):

> As of March 2021, 42 states have emergency regulations or price-gouging statutes ... Some states that do not have a specific statute addressing price gouging, can nevertheless apply the law as an "unfair" or "deceptive practice" under a consumer protection act.

So it appears that price gouging isn't explicitly legal in any of the 50 states, even if some states lack an explicit law prohibiting it. Are there other countries where price gouging is completely legal and regularly practiced during emergencies? To clarify "completely legal" refers to a situation where either the practice is explicitly legal **or** where its not explicitly banned and the government doesn't attempt to use related laws to implicitly ban it in practice.

According to some economists price gouging is actually good:

> According to the theory of neoclassical economics, anti-price gouging laws prevent allocative efficiency. Allocative efficiency refers to when prices function properly, markets tend to allocate resources to their most valued uses. In turn, those who value the good the most and are able to afford it will pay a higher price than those who do not value the good as much or who are unable to afford it.

So it would be interesting to see whether or not price gouging works out favorably for consumers in practice.

Comment: Are you asking if there are laws saying it is legal or just not laws prohibiting it?

Comment: @JoeW thanks, updated

Comment: "Asking for a friend"

Comment: @Punintended asking to understand whether or not the idea that "pricegouging = good" is true or not.

Comment: Are you asking in a purely economic sense? I can tell you don't live in a place that gets hit by natural disasters like hurricanes, tornadoes, wildfires, floods, earthquakes, mudslides, ...

Comment: Do some economists think that poor people dying in a natural disaster because they are unable to afford it is good?

Comment: @Azor the theory is that price gouging laws result in shortages which harms everyone more than increased prices. For an example see mask shortages in March 2020 or fuel shortages in some states this May.

Comment: How can a wealthy person value food, masks, or gas more than a poor person?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- the idea is that raising price on food would encourage other entrepreneurs to swarm in and provide more food to the area, rather than food (or toilet paper) becoming sold out and not available to anyone at all.

Comment: This appears to be a "what is the law" question, not a "why is this the law" or "how did this become the law" question. So this question belongs to law stack exchange, not politics stack exchange. I will migrate it there.

Comment: This question could be phrased as in where are businesses allowed to charge what the market will bear  without being harassed, fined,  or imprisoned by state actors. That being said, likely none, as "price-gouging" is good for re-election of politicians. Better to be grasshopper than an ant in these United States currently.

Comment: @paulj good point! Edited. And yes, its sad that politicians are extremely populist everywhere.

Comment: The bakery next door to my house may try to raise the price of a bread piece to $1,000 and no law would forbid them. But they will end broke as everybody would buy elsewhere. But if all of the bakeries at my city raised the price to $1,000 it would mean that they are doing price-fixing or a monopoly, which is prosecuted by a different law. Frankly, the question is so badly defined that giving an answer is quite difficult. Do anti-monopoly law mean anti-gouging? Do laws that apply only during emergencies count?

Comment: @SJuan76 Anti-monopoly laws don't count. Emergency-only laws do count. So a bakery would be free to jack up prices during a hurricane but not call around and ask other bakeries to do so in sync.

Comment: And for "raising price on food would encourage other entrepreneurs to swarm in and provide more food", during emergencies there is no time to increase production significantly (it is not that elastic) and that other factors may mean (for example, transport difficult. Mask shortages in 2020 did not happen because its price was low, they did happen because there production capabilities do not appear overnight, no matter what you pay for them.

Comment: @SJuan76 if price gouging was allowed on masks, people would rush to sell their own supplies back to the stores to make a quick buck, rather than hoarding them for their own use - I know several people who owned multiple boxes of N95 masks despite working from home. Plus manufacturing would've caught up faster as equipment owners would have a bigger incentive to hurry and ramp up production, so that they get a chance to sell masks at hugely inflated prices. With prices being static the incentive was quite weak.

Answer (score 0):

The US is one country without laws prohibiting price gouging. Individual states may have some specific law, but the US as a whole does not. Washington state is a state which (surprisingly) has no such law. Texas (surprisingly) [has such a law](https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/consumer-protection/disaster-and-emergency-scams/how-spot-and-report-price-gouging), specifically §17.46(b)(27) of the Texas Deceptive Trade Practices-Consumer Protection Act, where they classify as a prohibited "false, misleading, or deceptive acts or practice"

> subject to Section 17.4625, taking advantage of a disaster declared by
> the governor under Chapter 418, Government Code, or by the president
> of the United States by:
>
> (A)  selling or leasing fuel, food, medicine, lodging, building
> materials, construction tools, or another necessity at an exorbitant
> or excessive price; or
>
> (B)  demanding an exorbitant or excessive price in connection with the
> sale or lease of fuel, food, medicine, lodging, building materials,
> construction tools, or another necessity

Things are never explicitly legal, instead they are explicitly illegal. The general rule is that that which is not prohibited is permitted.

Comment: Unfortunately stores in WA were still harassed for setting prices at market levels: https://www.krem.com/article/news/health/coronavirus/wash-ags-office-sends-investigators-to-stores-accused-of-price-gouging/293-336e5b22-d05b-4338-bbc6-c68ab465a43d. Is there a state in the US where stores were able to raise prices without facing harassment from state or federal authorities?